# Doing explicit replays in axon 3.x

Tags: axon

I have been trying out axon recently and read lots of stuff. From what I understand, the concept of event sourcing says that system state is rebuilt from the event store, while CQRS updates a view model that can be queried with the command side side is not queryable.

1. I will like to implement rebuilding of state myself each time the UI requests for some information. I've implemented the event processor and seen its replay capabilities. However I can't seem to find any evidence that axon allows for replays triggered on user demand. Therefore I'm asking here if its possible to personally trigger a replay to build a DAO required by the UI or axon only supports the CQRS way of doing it.
2. When axon does a replay (when token is deleted), does it read from the snapshot table (if implemented), then from the event table or does it always start from the beginning of time?

Answer (score 2):

1. Dropping the token manually is currently the way to go if you want your query side to be rebuilt.
   So, if you'd like to trigger a replay, you'd have to add a component which does that for you.
   This might be a tricky process as well, since you'd probably not want any other parties trying to access  your view(s) while they're rebuilding.
   Take note that for this you do need to put your event handling components in a `TrackingEventProcessor`, otherwise it will have no recollection of how much of the events it has handled or not in the form of a `TrackingToken`.
2. The snapshot table is meant for your aggregates to ease the loading process. When you've set up axon to use the `(Caching)EventSourcingRepository`, it will first load an aggregate based on a snapshot and then source the remaining events.
   So, to answer your second question: when you drop the token, it will read from the domain event entry table from the beginning of time.

Hope this helps!

### Update

For those looking for replay support in Axon Framework, it is recommended to look at [this](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/events/event-processors/streaming#replaying-events) page of the Reference Guide. It describes the replay support constructed for Streaming Event Processsors (like the `TrackingEventProcessor`).

Comment: Thanks Steven. Since the aggregate loading is made efficient through snapshots, I would like to take advantage of that. What I want to do is similar to what an aggregate does, i.e rebuilding a materialized view on the fly from the event store instead of storing it in a database (ES way). Do you know an example of any such implementation, or a proposition to make?

Comment: Hmm I'm not familiar with out of the box examples of what you want, but I'd say copying what the `EventSourcingRepository` does to suite your needs sounds like the best approach.

I did once make a `ReplayingRepository`, which grabbed an event stream from the `EventStore` based on an `aggregateIdentifier` and replayed those events against an `EventListener`.

You could create your own event handling class and wrap it in an `EventListener` by using the `AnnotationEventListenerAdapter`, if you're planning to take that route.

This however doesn't support the snapshotting bit!

Comment: Any update on this as of 2021 (Axon Framework 4.5)... I'm thinking at least if all of the data a particular projection needs is in the Aggregate snapshot, it'd be much better to "reseed" the projection database (after dropping it on reset) with the last Aggregate snapshot properties, _then_ replay all _subsequent_ events... (wouldn't work for view fields derived or external to he aggregate...but..)

Comment: Axon's Event Sourcing solution basically is a recreation of your Command Model every time. Axon supports snapshotting on this level to optimize the loading (thus, the replay) for you. Axon doesn't support this for the query side (the topic at hand), as nothing dictates a query model is only based on a single Aggregate stream. The so-called sequencing order oftentimes is the aggregate stream, true, but there is no certainty in this. As such, replaying a single query model is, right now, some handy workers users need to do themselves.

Comment: Nonetheless, the replay support has definitely been expanded since this question's been answered. Check out this page in the Reference Guide to read more about Event Processor replaying - https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/events/event-processors/streaming#replaying-events